# Pyspark: wrong results for calculating min and avg after groupby

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe with columns `id` (`date_from`) and `price`. Example:

```
id          date_from   price
10000012    2021-08-12  19283.334
10000012    2021-05-16  4400.0
10000012    2021-06-08  5718.69
10000012    2021-07-09  15283.333
10000012    2021-07-02  9087.5
10000012    2021-07-04  15283.333
10000012    2021-06-22  9061.111
10000012    2021-06-26  9076.667
10000012    2021-06-27  9080.77
10000012    2021-07-10  15283.333
10000012    2021-08-14  19283.334
10000012    2021-05-09  4400.0
10000012    2021-05-12  4400.0
10000012    2021-06-17  9065.64
10000012    2021-05-19  4400.0
10000166    2021-05-06  5801.4287
10000166    2021-04-01  4954.375
10000166    2021-04-22  5173.7856
10000166    2021-06-27  12655.429
10000166    2021-02-23  5167.5
```

I want to calculate the min price and average price. For that I have tried:

```
groupBy_id = ["id"]
aggregate = ["price"]
funs = [min, mean]
exprs = [f(col(c)) for f in funs for c in aggregate]
df = df.groupby(*groupBy_id).agg(*exprs)
```

And also:

```
df = df.groupby("id").agg(min("price").alias("min(norm_price)"),avg("price").alias("avg(norm_price)"))
```

But some of the `min(norm_price)` values are larger than `avg(norm_price)` ones.
Output:

```
id,min(norm_price),avg(norm_price)
10000012,11150.0,10287.276085889778
10000166,10370.761904761903,6082.360302835207
10000185,5054.642857142857,5424.533834586466
10000421,3990.0,3990.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure norm_price is of double type, not string type. Otherwise `min` will return the minimum string, not the minimum number.

```
df = df.withColumn('price', col('price').cast('double'))
df = df.groupby(*groupBy_id).agg(*exprs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something fairly simple:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import (
     StringType,
     StructField,
     StructType,
     FloatType
)
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

schema = StructType([
     StructField('id', StringType(), True),
     StructField('date', StringType(), True),
     StructField('price', FloatType(), True)
])
df = spark.read.csv(
        "price.csv",
        header='true',
        schema=schema
)
df.groupBy("id").agg(F.avg('price'), F.min('price')).show()
```

This gives me desired result:
[image]